# Need my AJAX call to send data to a private method of the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, variables, methods, controller

I made an AJAX call to send one javascript variable to one method in my controller. My controller looks like this :

```js
def registration
      @fund = params[:funds]
      @index = params[:indexDecision]

      render json: 'ok'

end


def create
    @user = User.new(ticket_params)
    
    
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }

        Record.create(fund: @funds, weight: @weight)

      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
      format.js
    end
  end
```

This is my AJAX call :

```js
$.ajax({
           url: "/record",
           type: "POST",
           data: {
             funds: funds,
             indexDecision: indexDecision
           },
           complete: function(){
             console.log('Congrats');
           }

         });
```

And this is my config route file :

```js
resources :users

post '/record' => 'users#registration'
```

My AJAX call works well. But now I would need the instance variable `@fund` and `@index` to be available in the create method. I read that I had to use private method so that the instance variables in the private method would be available in other methods.

I tried but I have an `error 400 bad request`.

**How can I do so that the @funds and @index variables can be available in the create method ?**

Comment: 1. move `@fund = params[:funds]` and `@index = params[:indexDecision]` to create action;
2. what is this `format.js` in the end of `create` action

Comment: But my AJAX call is sending the parameters to the registration method. How are they gonna be available in the create method ? Just doing @fund=params[:funds] ? format.js is there so that I can use .js.erb files that's the way AJAX call works according to the tutorial of Ruby on Rails available on CodeSchool

Comment: Which one are you calling in your request?

Comment: I edited my post to show you how I make my AJAX call and the config route file

Comment: I've also updated my answer. It should work for JSON format only.

Comment: Yes but the reason why I need my parameters to be available in the create method is that the line `Record.create(:fund @funds, :weight @weight)`needs to be run only if the user is created so in the create method I have to insert this line after the `if user.save` You can see what I want to do in my post I edited it

Comment: Then add user creation in registration action

Comment: I can't. The create action must be triggered only if a user click on the button.

Comment: In fact the user is making choices on the webpage, I store its choice in a javascript variable and sent it via an AJAX call to the registration method. Then the user is going to click on the button to create a User and in the same time a Record with the parameter `@fund` and `@weight`

Comment: Ok. Then pass user_id to registration action to know who is the user

Comment: You don't understand I would like to use my parameter only if the user is created. You can see in my controller and in the create method that there is a line that says `if @user.save`....after this `if`condition I'd like to use my parameter. If I do operations in the registration method it is going to be executed in the same time that the AJAX call thus it is the AJAX call that triggers the registration method. All I want is a two steps operation. First step is my AJAX call that sent my parameters to the registration method. Second step the create method use these parameters

Comment: You should store your parameters in database then. And use it when user is actually created.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88466/discussion-between-dimakura-and-gdmn).

Answer (score 0):

Your code should probably look like this (I ignored HTML format for simplicity):

```
def registration
  user = User.new(ticket_params)
  if user.save
    fund = params[:funds]
    index = params[:indexDecision]
    Record.create(fund: funds, weight: weight)
    render json: 'ok'
   else
     # report error here
   end
end
```

Comment: Do I have to keep the render json: 'ok' in my registration method ?

Comment: Yes, you should. It was not clear though why do you need `@fund` and `@index` in `registration` action? They were not used anyway.

Comment: It is my AJAX call that send this parameters to the registration method. Because when I tried to send this parameters to the the create method it failed with error 400 bad request

Comment: Then you have issue with `create` method. Can you post what it looks like now?

Comment: Yes I am gonna show you. I edited my post to show you how I want to use these parameters. Thanks for your help